# Insertar un valor a una llave foránea

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trato de insertar el ultimo id de una tabla e insertarla a otra. Estas tablas están relacionadas en la tabla B. Me inserta normal, tomo ese ID de la tabla B y la quiero insertar en la Tabla A, solo que me marca error al querer insertar este ID.
Ya intente convertir ese valor a int pero sigue dando error.

```
   static public function InsertUser ( $tabla , $data , $PassHash , $Fecha, $idRol )
    {
        $conectar = Conexion ::conectar ();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabla
            (Nombre,
            Usuario,
            Password,
            Email,
            Fecha_creada,
            FK_usuarios_rol)
            VALUES ( :Nombre, :Usuario, :Password, :Perfil , :Fecha, :rol) ";
        $sql = $conectar -> prepare ( $sql );
        $sql -> bindParam ( ":Nombre" , $data[ "Nombre" ] ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql -> bindParam ( ':Usuario' , $data[ "Usuario" ] , PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sql -> bindParam ( ':Password' , $PassHash , PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sql -> bindParam ( ':Email' , $data[ "Email" ] , PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sql -> bindParam ( ':Fecha' , $Fecha , PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $sql -> bindParam (  ":rol" , $idRol , PDO::PARAM_INT );
        if ( $sql -> execute ()) {
            return json_encode ("Registro completo");
        } else {
            return json_encode ( 'HUbo un error al inmsertar el usuario' );
        }
        return $res = $sql -> fetchAll ();
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es un typo. En la variable de consulta `$sql` tienes `:Perfil` y en `bindParam` tienes `:Email`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparte del *typo* que te ha señalado certeramente @aeportugal considera mejorar tu código. El `return $res = $sql -> fetchAll ();` no tiene ningún sentido, y esto por dos motivos:

1. Cuando hay un `return` no se ejecuta nada más de lo que sigue, por tanto, el código no llegará nunca a esa línea.
2. Aunque tuvieras bien colocado ese `return`, no aplica `fetchAll()` para una consulta de tipo `INSERT`. Más bien deberías verificar con `rowCount()`. Y es que de hecho, la única forma de saber si un registro fue insertado en verificando con `rowCount()`. Verificar el éxito de la consulta no implica que necesariamente se hayan insertado registros.

Por otra parte, tampoco tiene mucho sentido retornar una cadena simple como JSON. Se suele enviar un array, de modo que al consumir la respuesta uses una lógica definida, por ejemplo, para manejar situaciones de éxito o de error.

Aplicando lo dicho, el código podría quedar así:

```
static public function InsertUser ( $tabla , $data , $PassHash , $Fecha, $idRol )
{
    #Array para la respuesta final
    $outPut=array();
    $conectar = Conexion ::conectar ();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabla
        (Nombre,
        Usuario,
        Password,
        Email,
        Fecha_creada,
        FK_usuarios_rol)
        VALUES ( :Nombre, :Usuario, :Password, :Email , :Fecha, :rol) ";
    $sql = $conectar -> prepare ( $sql );
    $sql -> bindParam ( ":Nombre" , $data[ "Nombre" ] ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql -> bindParam ( ':Usuario' , $data[ "Usuario" ] , PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $sql -> bindParam ( ':Password' , $PassHash , PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $sql -> bindParam ( ':Email' , $data[ "Email" ] , PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $sql -> bindParam ( ':Fecha' , $Fecha , PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $sql -> bindParam (  ":rol" , $idRol , PDO::PARAM_INT );
    if ( $sql -> execute () ) {
        $total= $sql -> rowCount();
        if ( $total > 0 ) {
            $outPut=array(
                           'status'=>true,
                           'msg' =>sprintf("Registro completo. Filas insertadas: %d",$total) 
                         );
        } else {
            $outPut=array(
                           'status'=>true,
                           'msg' =>"Ningún registro insertado" 
                         );
        }
    } else {
        $outPut=array(
                       'status'=>false,
                       'msg' =>'Error al ejecutar la consulta' 
                     );
    }
    return json_encode($outPut);
}
```

Allí donde consumas la respuesta, podrás ahora hacer algo como esto:

```
if( $laRespuesta['status'] ) {
    # Todo OK, mostrar el mensaje que venga 
    # en $laRespuesta['msg'] o lo que sea
} else {
    # Hubo error, lanzar política de errores 
    # o mostrar mensaje con el estilo definido
    # para errores o lo que sea
}
```

### PD:

- Quedaría por definir si, según la naturaleza de tu aplicación, el caso del `else` en el `if` anidado es un caso de error o no. Diríamos que desde el punto de vista del código no hubo error, en el sentido de que la consulta funcionó, pero por algún motivo ningún registro fue insertado y eso podría ser un error en cuanto a la lógica, si en la concepción de la aplicación sólo serán exitosos los casos en que uno o más registros sean insertados. Cabe decir que esto es menos probable en un caso de `INSERT`, pero que puede ser muy frecuente en un caso de `UPDATE` o `DELETE`, porque en esos casos, una consulta con un criterio `WHERE` que no se cumpla será exitosa en sí misma, pero no actualizará / borrará ningún registro porque el criterio no se cumplió. O, en una consulta del tipo `UPDATE` en la que intentes actualizar una o más columnas con los mismos valores que ya tiene, ningún `UPDATE` ocurrirá, aunque la ejecución de la consulta en sí misma sea exitosa.
- Convendría, en entornos como estos, controlar otras cosas, como la validez de la conexión, el estado de las variables que se van a insertar (que no estén vacías o nulas, etc). No sé si lo haces en otra parte del programa.